# MYSQL insert into table with one column's data pulled from another table

Tags: mysql, insert, insert-update, validation

**line item table**
`line_item_id` 
`order_id`,
 
`quantity`, 
`unit_price`,
`shipping_price`, 
`business_id`,
`item_id`,

**Inventory table**   
item_id 
pos_code 
description 
sku_count   
unit_price

When I do an insert into the Line items table; the unit price should  match what is there in the inventory table. Instead of relying on the client's data, I would like to insert what is present in the inventory table.

```
insert into line_items(`order_id`,  `quantity`, `unit_price`, `shipping_price`, `business_id`,`item_id`)
    values(1, 1, select unit_price from inventory where item_id=1, 10, 1, 1);
```

This syntax is incorrect.But I am not able to figure out how to re-write this.

Or is there an alternative that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into line_items(`order_id`,  `quantity`, `unit_price`, `shipping_price`, `business_id`, `item_id`)
   select 1, 1, unit_price, 10, 1, 1
   from inventory
   where item_id = 1;
```

Comment: @user5118993 . . . It is only possible to answer the question presented.  If you have another question, then please ask it as *another* question.  This version is pretty clear that there are only two tables.  I would also suggest that you include layouts for the tables and a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I misinterpreted the answer. Understood how the sql works now. Thanks for your answer.